# Fitting a VAR model

Tags: stationarity, vector-autoregression, trend

I have a data set which is needed to get a multivariate time series model fitted. Possible time series models for now is VAR and VEC models. Assume that the variables are not cointegrated, so we try to  fit a VAR model.
In that case, the stationarity of data is mandatory. To test the stationarity, I conducted the following test, using R software;

```
kpss.test(variable_1, null = "Trend")
```

as the time series plot of variable_1 showed some trend (not level).

As a result of this test, I got variable_1 is stationary. But I know, that variable_1 has a trend (may be a deterministic trend, but not a stochastic trend).

My problem here is, since variable_1 is stationary, can I use it directly in fitting a VAR model? Don't I have to detrend it, as I know it has a trend component, though the test says variable_1 is stationary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either the variable is stationary, or it has a deterministic time trend; the two are not compatible. (There is also a notion of trend-stationarity, which applies to a nonstationary series that becomes stationary once a deterministic trend is removed from it.) In general:

- If the variable is stationary, go ahead and use it in a VAR.
- If it has a deterministic trend, either detrend it first and use the remainder in a VAR or include a time trend as an exogenous variable in the VAR model.

Regarding your case, the KPSS test has a null hypothesis that a time series is stationary around a deterministic trend (i.e. trend-stationary) against the alternative of a unit root. Hence, you cannot get a result indicating that the series is stationary (only trend-stationary). If you rejected the null, you would suspect a unit root; if you did not, you would assume a deterministic time trend. In either case, look at the two bullet points above.

Comment: Simple and clear. Thanks a lot for the answer.

Comment: @DoviniJayasinghe, thank you!